# how to use syntax in geom_polygon?

Tags: r, ggplot2

sorry for the question, I am still new in this. I found a nice code in the internet which shades areas between graphs with polygon (I cannot use geom_ribbon). I have to rewrite it into the ggplot format, but I dont know which parameters I have to plug in.

```
#sample code
x1 <- seq(-3,3,0.01)
y1 <- dnorm(x,0,1)
y2 <- 0.5*dnorm(x,0,1)
plot(x1,y1,type="l",bty="L")
polygon(c(x1,rev(x1)),c(y2,rev(y1)),col="skyblue")


#I need the code in this format
d=data.frame(x1=x1, y1=y1, y2=y2)
ggplot(data= d) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x1,y=y1))+
  geom_line(aes(x=x1,y=y2))+
  geom_polygon(?????)
```

Does anyone know a solution? Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the use of a second data frame (`d2`):

```
x1 <- seq(-3,3,0.01)
y1 <- dnorm(x1,0,1)
y2 <- 0.5*dnorm(x1,0,1)
d1 <- data.frame(x1=x1, y1=y1, y2=y2)
idx <- order(x1)
d2 <- data.frame(x=c(x1[idx],x1[rev(idx)]), 
                 y=c(y1[idx],y2[rev(idx)]))

ggplot(data=d1) +
  geom_polygon(data=d2, aes(x=x, y=y), fill="skyblue", color="black") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: You don't need the two `geom_line` statements - `color = "black"` draws the lines in the `geom_polygon` statement.